# Como puedo evitar que un card dentro de un col-md-8 sea muy grande en Bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap-4, card

En un row tengo dos cards una en un col-md-4 y el otro en col-md-8. El problema es que la card de la columna más grande tiene mayores proporciones. Quisiera saber como puedo mantener la altura de las cartas anteriores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
<div class = "container">
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
           <img class="card-img-top" src="image/algoritmia.jpg" alt="Card image cap 4">
           <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">Ejercicio 4</h4>
              <br><br>
              <a href="algoritmia.html" class="btn btn-primary">Ver más</a>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 image-fluid">
        <div class="card">
           <img class="card-img-top" src="image/semana.jpg" alt="Card image cap 5">
           <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">Ejercicio 5</h4>
              <br><br>
              <a href="semana.html" class="btn btn-primary">Ver más</a>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para mantener la altura de la columna puedes utizar la clase [d-flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) de bootstrap. quedaría de la siguiente manera: class="col-md-4 d-flex"

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class = "container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 d-flex" >
        <div  class="card">
           <img class="card-img-top" src="image/algoritmia.jpg" alt="Card image cap 4">
           <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">Ejercicio 4</h4>
              <form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
              <br><br>
              <a href="algoritmia.html" class="btn btn-primary">Ver más</a>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 image-fluid d-flex">
        <div class="card">
           <img class="card-img-top" src="image/semana.jpg" alt="Card image cap 5">
           <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">Ejercicio 5</h4>
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
              
             
              <br><br>
              <a href="semana.html" class="btn btn-primary">Ver más</a>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>

</div>
```